# NOT operator for regex

Tags: python, regex

Using python script, I am cleaning a piece of text where I want to replace following words:
**promocode, promo, code, coupon, coupon code, code.**

However, *I dont want to replace them if they start with a '#'.* Thus, **#promocode, #promo, #code, #coupon** should remain the way they are.

I tried following regex for it:

```
1. \b(promocode|promo code|promo|coupon code|code|coupon)\b
2. (?<!#)(promocode|promo code|promo|coupon code|code|coupon)
```

None of them are working. **I am basically looking something that will allow me to say "Does NOT start with # and"** (promocode|promo code|promo|coupon code|code|coupon)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: How did you apply it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a negative look-behind:

```
(?<!#)\b(?:promocode|promo code|promo|coupon code|code|coupon)\b
```

This `(?<!#)` will ensure you will only match these words if there is no `#` before them and `\b` will ensure you only match whole words. The non-capturing group `(?:...)` is used just for grouping purposes so as not to repeat `\b` around each alternative in the list (e.g. `\bpromo\b|\bcode\b`...). Why use non-capturing group? So that it does not interfere with the `Match` result. We do not need unnecessary overhead with digging out the values (=groups) we need.

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/rV9oY3/1)

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/LarrSU), only the first `promo` is deleted:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<!#)\b(?:promocode|promo code|promo|coupon code|code|coupon)\b')
test_str = "promo #promo "
print(p.sub('', test_str))
```

A couple of words about your regular expressions.

The `\b(promocode|promo code|promo|coupon code|code|coupon)\b` is good, but it also matches the words in the alternation group not preceded with `#`.

The `(?<!#)(promocode|promo code|promo|coupon code|code|coupon)` regex is better, but you still do not match whole words (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV9oY3/2)).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev I tired using look behind as in (2) but it didnt work. Looks like ?: in (?: promocode.....) is important. Can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: I added some more explanations, if you have any specific doubts, please feel free to drop more comments here.